# mailto:recipients is not working with UIActivityViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using ActivityViewController for sending mail from App.

I was able to auto fill subject and body but not participants.

Example code :

```
NSURL *recipients = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:foo@bar.com"]; //Not working                
        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[recipients, @"bodyText"]
                                          applicationActivities:nil];
        [activityViewController setValue:mailSubject forKey:@"Subject"];

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];



        [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                                animated:YES
                                              completion:^{

                                              }];
```

MailTo participants is not working.
When i run the code, pop up is coming with selected mail app but to field is empty.

Comment: `UIActivityViewController` doesn't handle `mailto` URLs. I submitted an enhancement request to Apple a while ago about this issue.